# Can't concatenate digit to variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to append a digit to my variables, but it isn't working. I've also tried with the '.' operator instead of the '+' but that doesn't work. I've even tried without the + or . (worksheetindex) and that doesn't work either. Kind of stuck here - would appreciate the help.

Here's the code:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('JAY_test.xlsx')
worksheet0 = workbook.add_worksheet('Toys Ordered')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Toys Shipped')

for index in range(len(case_queries)):
    cur.execute(case_queries[index])
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    # Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
    row = 0
    col = 0

    # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
    for return_date, return_hour, return_count in (rows):
        worksheet+index.write(row, col,     str(return_date))
        worksheet+index.write(row, col + 1, return_hour)
        workshweet+index.write(row, col + 2, return_count)
        row += 1
```

The error that I receive is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    worksheet+index.write(row, col,     str(return_date))
NameError: name 'worksheet' is not defined
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x2173c10>> ignored
```

Comment: You seem to be confused on how names work in python.  `worksheet+index` is not how you would access `worksheet0`.

Comment: Obviously, that's why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of naming is not gonna work. You should use [lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) instead.

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('JAY_test.xlsx')
worksheet = []
worksheet.append(workbook.add_worksheet('Toys Ordered')) # worksheet[0]
worksheet.append(workbook.add_worksheet('Toys Shipped')) # worksheet[1]

for index in range(len(case_queries)):
    cur.execute(case_queries[index])
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    # Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
    row = 0
    col = 0

    # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
    for return_date, return_hour, return_count in (rows):
        worksheet[index].write(row, col,     str(return_date))
        worksheet[index].write(row, col + 1, return_hour)
        worksheet[index].write(row, col + 2, return_count)
        row += 1
```